# Change active link icon to a semi circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a list of links `li` and I want to add a semi-circle icon below an active link.How can I add this icon or at least change the arrow to a semi-circle.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="current">Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Location</li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS**

```
ul {
  li {
    display:inline;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    padding:20px 30px;
    position:relative;
    &:hover {
      background-color:#c0c0c0;
      cursor:pointer;
      &:after {
        border-top:#c0c0c0;
      }
    }
    &.current {
      &:after {
      width: 0;
      height: 10px;
      border-left: 15px solid transparent;
      border-right: 15px solid transparent;
      border-top: 15px solid #FFFFFF;
      content:" ";
      border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -20px;
      left: 35%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
  $('.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

working snippet :

```js
$('ul li').click(function() {
  $('.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:hover:after {
  border-top: #c0c0c0;
}

ul li.current:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #FFFFFF;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="current">Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Location</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's matching ur requirements and if i understood correctly but to have semi-circle on active class element. You can just add to li `overflow: hidden;` to be sure circle isnt out of container. Then simply you just add styling to ::after pseudoclass like this

```
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
bottom: 0;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
```

You simply create 15px radius circle which half of his is out of box which has overflow: hidden and that's it. You have semi circle at the bottom of ur li.

Of course this styling has to be added what u currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You had it pretty well done already.  All I did was change your sass to regular CSS so it would work in the snippet and then mess with the positioning a bit.

**Edit:** Added a better semicircle.

```js
$('ul li').click(function() {
  $('.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
ul li {
    display:inline;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    padding:20px 30px;
    position:relative;
}
ul li:hover {
    background-color:#c0c0c0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul li:hover::after {
    border-top:#c0c0c0;
}
ul li.current::after {
    background-color: #fff;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: calc(50% - 15px);
    height: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="current">Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Location</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your CSS and added comments so you can see which properties are implicated.

You can adjust according to your preferences.

```js
$('ul li').click(function() {
  $('.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  font-family: calibri, helvetica, arial;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  position: relative;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.current:after {
  content: " ";
  
  /* positioning */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
  /* half circle */
  background: #0f9def;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px; /* half of the width */
  height: 15px; /* half of the width */
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="current">Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Location</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do it, I would do it this way:

```
&.current {
  &:after {
    font-size: 32px;
    content: " \25D6";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 35px;
    color: white;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```